# Counting number of generated triangles

Tags: opengl

I am using tessellation shaders to generate new triangles.I use **layout(vertices = 3) out;** mode in TCS and **layout(triangles, equal_spacing)** in the TES shader.So I want basically to count how many new triangles has been generated.

I query that info like this:

```
     glBeginQuery(GL_PRIMITIVES_GENERATED,tessQuery);

    ///draw here///

     glEndQuery(GL_PRIMITIVES_GENERATED);
     GLuint numPrimitives = 0;
     glGetQueryObjectuiv(tessQuery, GL_QUERY_RESULT,&numPrimitives);
```

But what I am not sure is what the result means.Does [GL_PRIMITIVES_GENERATED](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glBeginQuery.xml) means -triangles in my case , or quads when the quads are tessellated?Can the meaning of "primitive" here be a face (2 adjacent triangles)?

Comment: I am not sure where quads are coming into this discussion. `GL_PRIMITIVES_GENERATED` is the number of primitives processed during primitive assembly (this happens after tessellation evaluation). It's basically the number of primitives emitted by geometry shaders.

Comment: And if I don't use geom stage,those are triangles?(if I use triangles in tess stage)?

Comment: Yeah, the Tessellation Evaluation Shader is either going to generate points, lines (isolines) or triangles (for triangle and quad patches). If you don't have a Geometry Shader it will be one of those things that is counted. It never generates quads.

Comment: why not test with a simple use case?

Comment: @ratchetfreak  because I wasn't sure how many triangles PATCH edge subdivision defs generate.